# Problem of displaying image using OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I wish to display image using c++ OpenCV code. Below are the code fragment:

```
//Load image
Mat img = imread("Example1.jpg");

//Display in window
namedWindow("Skin");

//display image
imshow("Skin",img);

//returns the matrix size
cout<<img.size()<<endl; // wrong
```

Please help on how to display the size. I have tried many times buy fail.

Comment: What do you mean with size? If you want the width and height, then use `img.width` and `img.height` or `img.cols` and `img.rows`. Otherwise, specify your question a bit.

Comment: Hi. Size in c is retrieved by: 
 cout<<"Image size:"<<img->imageSize<<endl;                        Now, just want to display it in C++. Sorry for the vague question. Tq

Comment: what is the width/height of Example1.jpg and what is the value of `img.size()` for you?

Comment: width = 309
height= 172
imageSize=159616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Load image
Mat img = imread("Example1.jpg");

//Display in window
namedWindow("Skin");

//display image
imshow("Skin",img);

//returns the matrix size
cout << "width= " << img.cols << " height= " << img.rows<< endl; 
//OR if you wanna use the size() getter.
cout << "width= " << img.size().width << " height= " << img.size().height << endl;
```

Comment: That may be what you wanted, but `imageSize` is not `width * height`.

Comment: ya. width*height is not same as the size.